# Using navigation drawer and toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I am developing an android app and I want to use a toolbar and a navigation drawer inside a fragment. I created an inner class named *Supportclass* and then use the method named *setUptoolbar* in the *onCreateView* method but I got an abnormal error.
What do you think i should do? Thank you in advance and sorry for my broken English. :)

Fragment code:

```
public class FragmentVRList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
    View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_vr,container,false);
    Generator generator = new Generator();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    AdapterVRList adapter = new AdapterVRList(getActivity(), Generator.getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    SupportClass supportClass = new SupportClass();
    supportClass.setUptoolbar(getActivity(),rootView);

    final TeacherNet teacher = new TeacherNet(getActivity());
    int Length = Generator.getData().size();

    final JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    for (int position = 1;position<Length;position++){
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        try {
                            object.put("vrcode","1");
                            teacher.SelectContent(object);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
            case 2:
                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            object.put("vrcode","2");
                            teacher.SelectContent(object);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            case 3:
                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            object.put("vrcode","3");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}

private class SupportClass extends AppCompatActivity{
    public void setUptoolbar(Activity activity, View view){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity,drawerLayout,toolbar,0,0);
        toggle.syncState();
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    }

}

}
```

This is the error:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference**

Comment: Activity inside a fragment! OMG

Comment: @BirendraSingh What do you mean? It's not an Activity, It's just a class and it extends AppCompatAcivity just for using the setSupportActionBar method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the wrong hierarchy. Correct way is:

> Activity -> contains your toolbar, drawer and fragment holder (e.g.
>   frame layout or viewpager)

Now if you want to open the drawer from some action in fragment you have to add abstract event listener in fragment which will be implemented by activity.

see this quick link on github for more : http://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer

Comment: It is the same thing I answered in a direct way.

Answer (score 1):

You are all the way wrong with your approach. You can do it without defining a new class which extends activity. You always have reference to underlying activity via `getActivity ()`. Even if you want to keep a reference just use `MainActivity a = (MainActivity) getActivity ()` assuming that your fragment is attached to `MainActivity`. Then operate on `a`. You are getting that error because you are using

```
SupportClass supportClass = new SupportClass();
```

Activities are started using `Context.startActivity(Intent intent)`. It seems that you don't intend to start new activity. You just want to change properties of underlying activity. So as I said above use 
`MainActivity a = (MainActivity) getActivity ()` and play with `a` like `a.setSupportActionBar ()`.